# MEF WPF - Cancel Application.Current.Shutdown() by plugins

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mef

are there any ways to cancel

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

background: i played with mef a little bit and put some plugins to my main app. if any plugin call

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

my main app shutdown too and i got no chance to cancel this. are there any ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It don't look like it. So instead of having your plugins do a shutdown, instead have them call some method in your application class that will handle the shutdown request for them. See below link also for more info.

http://www.skylark-software.com/2009/10/canceling-application-shutdown-in-wpf.html