# Cancel a window closing in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am aware that this question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101801/cancel-wpf-application-current-shutdown), but I would have thought the following code would have canceled the shutdown request, but it doesn't? Can anyone explain why?

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(MainWindow_Closing);            

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms597013.aspx):

> Important: When Shutdown is called,
>   the application will shut down
>   irrespective of whether the Closing
>   event of any open windows is canceled.