# Keep WPF application alive on Closing

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

There are questions about this already, but this is a bit different so I'm asking. 
This is my xaml inside Window :

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClosingCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

This is closing Command :

```
public virtual ICommand ClosingCommand
{
    get { return new RelayCommand(ClosingExecute); }
}
```

This is Execute :

```
public virtual void ClosingExecute()
{
   MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Close the application?", "Shut Down", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);

    if(result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
    else
    {
       //I don't know what to write
    }

}
```

How can I keep my application alive in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just do nothing? What causes the app to close the code doesn't enter your if statement?

Comment: When I click no, the application shuts down. I guess it's because  it's in Closing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101801/mef-wpf-cancel-application-current-shutdown-by-plugins discusses about Close rather than shutdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing(v=vs.110).aspx) of `Closing`

> Closing can be handled to detect when a window is being closed (for example, when Close is called). Furthermore, Closing can be used to prevent a window from closing. To prevent a window from closing, you can set the Cancel property of the CancelEventArgs argument to true.

You need to hook up an event handler to this event and set `Cancel` to `true`.

If you want to do this in an mvvmy way, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6205643/1556026) might help you hook up your eventargs to the command parameter

Answer (score 1):

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
    ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown">
</Application>

ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9992888/3855622